# Java escaping hyphen "-" character using regex

Tags: java

I am using Java and have string which have value as shown below,

```
String data = "vale-cx";
data = data.replaceAll("\\-", "\\-\\");
```

I am replacing "-" inside of it and it is not working. Final value i am looking is "vale\-cx". Meaning, hyphen needs to be escaped.

Comment: Meaning the hyphen *doesn't* need to be escaped.

Comment: Stack over flow have eaten one back slash. I edited the question.

Comment: I think he means that it needs to be escaped in the *language* of the final value of `data`.  Which is a pretty odd / confusing way of describing his problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `\\\\-` instead, e.g:

```
String data = "vale-cx";
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("\\-", "\\\\-"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Hyphen doesn't need to be escaped, but backslash needs to be escaped in the replacement expression, meaning you need an extra two backslashes before the hyphen (and none after):

```
data = data.replaceAll("-", "\\\\-");
```

Better yet, don't use regex at all:

```
data = data.replace("-", "\\-");
```

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen is only special in regular expressions when used to create ranges in character classes, e.g. `[A-Z]`. You aren't doing that here, so you don't need any escaping at all.

Comment: He does need escaping in the replacement.

Comment: @shmosel No he doesn't. The [second argument is a `String`, not a regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api//java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: You might want to read it more carefully yourself. It says 'Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string': no such warning about hyphens; and if you chase the [link to `replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api//java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) it specifically gives an example with an unescaped `-` in the replacement string.

Comment: Hmm... maybe you need to read the question more carefully. OP wants to insert a backslash.